# pasar datos de un checkbox a caja de texto

Tags: javascript

Quiero pasar una palabra cuando se acciona un checkbox a una caja de texto.
Ejemplo de palabra a pasar: DATOS.
Lo he probado pero no funciona.
Alguna sugerencia?

```
  <script language="javascript"> function PasarValor() { 
 document.getElementById("nombre2").value = 'DATOS'; } 
 
 </script>

 <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action=""> 
 
 <input type="checkbox" id="nombre1" value="PasarValor();"
 class="form-control">
 
 <input type="text"  id="nombre2" placeholder="Recibe contenido" 
 class="form-control">  
 
 </form>
```

Comment: Edita la publicacion, y pon el codigo como codigo `{ }` ... yo te habia corregido el error. Borra los comentarios igual.

Answer (score 1):

Es un error de sintaxis, si te fijas has puesto la llamada al método en la propiedad value de tu input, lo correcto seria usar la propiedad onClick, de esta manera:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nombre1" onClick="PasarValor()" class="formcontrol">
```